# Mysterious react-router error

Tags: react-router

I am using react-router 2.6.1 and have the following code in the top module.

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Route, IndexRoute, Router} from 'react-router';
import App from "components/app"
import FindView from "components/find";
import RememberView from "components/remember";
import MetaView from "components/meta";
import ExploreView from "components/explore";


render((
  <Router>
    <Route name='pkm' path='/' component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={RememberView} />
      <Route name="remember" path="remember" component={RememberView} />
      <Route name="find" path="find" component={FindView} />
      <Route name="meta" path="meta" component={MetaView} />
      <Route name="explore" path="explore" component={ExploreView} />
    </Route>
  </Router>), document.getElementById('content'));
```

I get the chrome devtools complaint at the render line of

invariant.js:38Uncaught Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.

However checking in the corsole document element is in fact found.  Any idea what this is or how this may be best debugged from here?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  The problem was where I was loading the script in the index.html it turns out.